# kineticjs setfill to one shape but some how other shapes got changed as well

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

jsfiddle.net/C62Xq/17/

What i want is:
   Top button will change color of top arch -- and nothing else
   Right,Left,Bottom,and middle cange color in that order respectively.

But 
why none of my setfill behave correctly.  The top button should change color of the top arch, but it modifies the circle as well. The rest of the button behave so weird.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put context.beginPath() at the start of each set of path commands**

beginPath starts a new path and discontinues the previous path.

Without a beginPath any new fill will apply to all previously drawn paths.

For example:

```
var middle = new Kinetic.Shape({ drawFunc: function (context) {

    // beginPath is required

    context.beginPath();

    context.moveTo(25 + xaxis, 125);
```

...And the same for top, bottom, left and right.

Fixed demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yFQ9F/